# My render is stretched and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: rendering

[image]

I really need help. In the viewport my render does not show its stretched but only when its been rendered as an image or animation

Comment: Hello, it looks like some vertices are not assigned to the correct vertex group, have you checked them?

Comment: I think the title of this question is misleading. It is not your render that is stretched, your model appears stretched only in final render.